# Is there any alternative for JEditorPane (which is in Swing) to implement in CodeName One?

Tags: codenameone

I have a requirement to make a component which can contain formatted text, image or url link. This type of component is available in Java Swing as **JEditorPane**. 
But I didn't get any this type of component or alternative in **CodeName One**. 
Can anybody suggest please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the web browser aspect of `JEditorPane` then the `WebBrowser` component should answer all your needs and more (actual native webkit).

However, I'm assuming you are looking for the rich text editing capabilities. Codename One doesn't have this builtin but Steve Hannah implemented a library that encapsulates a JavaScript rich text editor and bridges it to Codename One using the web browser component: https://github.com/shannah/cn1-ckeditor which should allow you roughly the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using WebBrowser component, but its length is not fitting in to its parent container. I tried setting its length using setHieght, which failed. Could you please suggest me how can i fix this component within a fixed size container?

Comment: You need to use layout managers, you can't use a fixed size. You must place it in the center of a border layout or something like that since its a peer component http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2014/05/understanding-peer-native-components-why-codename-one-is-so-portable.html